# I think I have problem in dimension in plt.plot

Tags: python, error-handling, compiler-errors, syntax-error, regression

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpdQd.png)

My plt.plot looks like this.

I want to plot liner line in the plt like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rETNe.png)

My code is like

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Preprocessing Input data
data = pd.read_csv('advertising.csv')
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12.0, 9.0)
X = data.iloc[:,0]
Y = data.iloc[:,-1]

plt.scatter(X,Y)
# Building the model
m = 2
c = 1

L = 0.01  # The learning Rate
epochs = 10  # The number of iterations to perform gradient descent

n = float(len(X)) # Number of elements in X

# Performing Gradient Descent 
for i in range(epochs): 
    Y_pred = m*X + c  # The current predicted value of Y
    D_m = (-2/n) * sum(X *(Y - Y_pred))  # Derivative wrt m
    D_c = (-2/n) * sum(Y - Y_pred)  # Derivative wrt c
    m = m - L * D_m  # Update m
    c = c - L * D_c  # Update c
    
print (m, c)

# Making predictions
Y_pred = m*X + c

plt.scatter(X, Y) 
plt.plot([min(X), max(X)], [min(Y_pred), max(Y_pred)], color='red')  # regression line
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should plot Y_pred instead of Y in the 2nd `plt.scatter`.It seems that new values of Y are in Y_pred, hence Y_pred should be used in plt.scatter insead of Y. The modified code is -

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Preprocessing Input data
data = pd.read_csv('advertising.csv')
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12.0, 9.0)
X = data.iloc[:,0]
Y = data.iloc[:,-1]

# plt.scatter(X,Y) # Not required
# Building the model
m = 2
c = 1

L = 0.01  # The learning Rate
epochs = 10  # The number of iterations to perform gradient descent

n = float(len(X)) # Number of elements in X

# Performing Gradient Descent 
for i in range(epochs): 
    Y_pred = m*X + c  # The current predicted value of Y
    D_m = (-2/n) * sum(X *(Y - Y_pred))  # Derivative wrt m
    D_c = (-2/n) * sum(Y - Y_pred)  # Derivative wrt c
    m = m - L * D_m  # Update m
    c = c - L * D_c  # Update c
    
print (m, c)

# Making predictions
Y_pred = m*X + c 

plt.scatter(X, Y_pred) #########  Y ---> Y_pred
plt.plot([min(X), max(X)], [min(Y_pred), max(Y_pred)], color='red')  # regression line
plt.show()
```